# Jedis (Redis) slows down

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, jedis

I am inserting lot of text into redis for storing frequency line by line. However , **jedis/ redis slows down and takes a lot of time to execut**e operation after a certain number of operations and **program ends with error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError .**

Here is my main file for testing :
    public class temp {

```
private ExecutorService executor;

public temp() {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    temp ob = new temp();

    System.out.println("starting");
    for(long i =0;i<10000000;i++) {
        if (i%10000 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        String x = Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt());
        ob.executor.submit(new Runner1("abra"+x));
        ob.executor.submit(new Runner2("delhi"+x));
    }

    try {
        if (ob.executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("completed");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

Here are my two runners: 
Runner 1:

```
public class Runner1 implements Runnable {
//private static RedisClientUtil redisClient = null;
private String key;
private static  Integer count = 0;

public Runner1(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void run() {
    try {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> cmd = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        String offer_title = this.key + " this is thread1";
        String offer_title_words[] = offer_title.split(" ");
        for (String word : offer_title_words) {
            // INCR the frequency in reddis
            cmd.add(GenerateUtils.getArrayList("incrBy", "test"+word, 1));
        }

        List<Object> responses = RedisbenchmarkTest.getLocalhostJedisPool().executePipelinedAndReturnResponses(0,cmd);
        cmd = null;
        responses = null;

        updateNumberOfRowsInserted();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private synchronized void updateNumberOfRowsInserted() {
        //logging
       count++;
        if(count%10000==0)
            System.out.println("Thread 1 : " + count);
    }



}
```

Runner 2:

```
public class Runner2 implements Runnable {
//private static RedisClientUtil redisClient = null;
private String key;
private static Integer count = 0;

public Runner2(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void run() {
    try {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> cmd = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        String offer_title = this.key + " this is thread2";
        String offer_title_words [] = offer_title.split(" ");
        for (String word  : offer_title_words) {
            // INCR the category_word in reddis
            cmd.add(GenerateUtils.getArrayList("incrBy","test1"+word,1));
        }                 RedisbenchmarkTest.getLocalhostJedisPool().executePipelinedWithoutReturningResponses(0,cmd);
        updateNumberOfRowsInserted();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private synchronized void updateNumberOfRowsInserted() {
    //logging
    count++;
    if(count%10000==0)
        System.out.println("Thread 2 : " + count);
}

}
```

Here is my Redis Client:

```
public class RedisbenchmarkTest {

   private static RedisClientUtil localhostJedisPool;


 private static final JedisPoolConfig standardJedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig() {{
    setMaxTotal(500);
    setMaxIdle(20);
    setMaxWaitMillis(500);
    setTestOnBorrow(false);
    setTestOnReturn(false);
}};

 private static final int semiLowTimeout = 500;

 static {
    initialize();
 }

 public static void initialize() {
    localhostJedisPool = new RedisClientUtil(
            standardJedisPoolConfig
            , "localhost"
            , 6379
            , semiLowTimeout
    );
  }



   public static RedisClientUtil getLocalhostJedisPool() {
      if (localhostJedisPool == null) {
          initialize();
   }
   return localhostJedisPool;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should disable bgsave in redis.conf If redis starts a bgsave usually huge lag is implied until the save finishes.
- You should ensure maxmemory in redis.conf is high enough. I guess your instance is running full.

Comment: # Memory
used_memory:23754992
used_memory_human:22.65M
used_memory_rss:27152384
used_memory_rss_human:25.89M
used_memory_peak:23754992
used_memory_peak_human:22.65M
total_system_memory:8589934592
total_system_memory_human:8.00G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.14
mem_allocator:libc

Comment: The memory is not used heavily according to INFO redis.

Comment: you can run "redis-cli info", then start your java application and see if the commands are handled immediately. Maybe jedis is batching the commands and causing the pauses?

Answer (score 0):

Redis isn't the one running out of memory, your Java process is.

You didn't post the actual error in its entirety and I am not a Java guy but [Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824134/caused-by-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) may hold some answers for you.

Comment: It's probably because Jedis is executing very slowly and eventually java goes out of memory.